# How to bulk suspend users in G-Suite

Tags: google-gsuite

I have a few hundred accounts that need to be suspended due to inactivity. I can "Download users" and get a CSV that includes "Last sign in" as a value, but the CSV of users data I get from "Bulk update users" does not.

My plan is to...

1. use "Download users" to get a CSV that contains the "Last sign in"
   value
2. in a text editor, extract the neglected accounts
3. format them to the "Bulk update users" specs
4. add "Suspended" to the "New Status [UPLOAD ONLY]" field
5. add "Suspended Accounts" to the "Org Unit Path [Required]" field
6. upload using "Bulk update users"

I think this will work, but I wonder if there's a better way to do this without adding any 3rd party access.

(Edited to add step 5, the organizational unit, which has to be created first, so that the suspended accounts can be more easily reviewed.)